Why does a popup menu not work in WINAPI?
I'm currently working on a Windows desktop app with the Windows API. I'm pretty new in the API, so I'm developing with some visual help provided by Visual Studio Community.
The structure is simple: I have a main window in which I put some textboxes and a menu.
If I create the window like this:
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int cShow) {

    MSG msg;
    HWND hVentana;

    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = cVentana;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MainWindowClass";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Fallo al registrar la clase de ventana.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    hVentana = CreateWindowEx(0, L"MainWindowClass", L"Emulador", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1600, 900, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);

    if (!hVentana) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Fallo al crear la ventana.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    HMENU hMenu = LoadMenu(hInst, L"IDD_MENU1");    // El menu está definido en resource.rc

    SetMenu(hVentana, hMenu);
    
    HWND hTextBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_READONLY | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE,
        10, 10, 387, 824, hVentana, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    
    HWND hRamBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_READONLY | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE,
        407, 477, 785, 309, hVentana, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    
    HWND hSearchBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
        407, 796, 785, 38, hVentana, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    HWND hTerminalBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_READONLY | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE,
        407, 60, 785, 405, hVentana, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    
    HWND hRegistrosBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_READONLY | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE,
        1202, 10, 374, 824, hVentana, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    ShowWindow(hVentana, cShow);
    UpdateWindow(hVentana);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

There's no problem.

But, if I do it like this:
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int cShow) {

    MSG msg;
    HWND hVentana;
    hVentana = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, cVentana);


    ShowWindow(hVentana, cShow);
    UpdateWindow(hVentana);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

The menu is shown, but if I hover on any item then it doesn't popup the item's option.

I have the menu resource and the dialog resource here:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Menu
//

IDD_MENU1 MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "Archivo"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Cargar programa",             ID_LOADPROGRAM
        MENUITEM "Cargar campaña",              ID_LOADCAMPAING
        MENUITEM "Salir",                       ID_EXIT
    END
    POPUP "Generar"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Informe de instrucciones",    ID_GENERAR_INFORMEDEINSTRUCCIONES
        MENUITEM "Archivo RAM",                 ID_GENERAR_ARCHIVORAM
    END
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 1600, 900
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Emulador"
MENU IDD_MENU1
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    EDITTEXT        IDC_TEXTBOX,10,10,387,824,ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_READONLY | NOT WS_TABSTOP
    EDITTEXT        IDC_RAMBOX,407,477,785,309,ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_READONLY | NOT WS_TABSTOP
    EDITTEXT        IDC_SEARCHBOX,407,796,785,38,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | NOT WS_TABSTOP
    EDITTEXT        IDC_TERMINALBOX,407,60,785,405,ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_READONLY | NOT WS_TABSTOP
    EDITTEXT        IDC_REGISTERSBOX,1202,10,374,824,ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_READONLY | NOT WS_TABSTOP
END

It would be nice to have all the dialog boxes in the resource file, so if there is any other way to make it, feel free to tell me.
NOTE: Also, for any reason, when I use the first form, the window's dimension are correct, but if I use the second form then the window is bigger than the dimensions I specified.

"The menu is shown, but if i hover on any item, it doesn't popup the menuitem's option" - what does that mean? Please clarify. Can you provide screnshots of what you are (or are not) seeing? What does cVentana look like in both cases?

@RemyLebeau I just edited the post with the working and not-working window examples

Message loop after CreateDialog is not the same like normal window. Read about Modeless dialog boxes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes#creating-a-modeless-dialog-box  About size - I hope you know that numbers are not pixels but 1/4 and 1/8 of dialog font.

@i486 what do you mean with "Message loop after CreateDialog is not the same like normal window"? I don't see difference.

@IkerRodríguezHernández I'm pretty new in the API -- Then I suggest getting books that have been written that goes through the aspects of WinAPI.  Books such as ones written by Charles Petzold come to mind.  The WinAPI is one of the least forgiving ones if you make the slightest of mistakes -- books have examples that are already tried and tested, with full explanations of what is going on.  Otherwise you could spend hours, days, and maybe weeks trying to figure out why some control acts strangely, or your dialog box doesn't show up, or why WM_whatever message code is not working.

@IkerRodríguezHernández See IsDialogMessage for modeless dialog.

@IkerRodríguezHernández Your application is responsible for retrieving and dispatching user input messages to the dialog box procedure.
The fourth parameter of CreateDialogW indicates that it is required DLGPROC callback function to handle the messages.  Also, as Remy Lebeau said, you need The loop checks the validity of the window handle to the dialog box and only calls the IsDialogMessage function if the handle is valid.

Msdn will help you understand it easily. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes#creating-a-modeless-dialog-box

When using CreateDialog(), you need to add IsDialogMessage() to your message loop before calling TranslateMessage()+DispatchMessage(), eg:
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int cShow) {

    HWND hVentana = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, cVentana);

    ShowWindow(hVentana, cShow);
    UpdateWindow(hVentana);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        if (!IsDialogMessage(hVentana, &msg)) { 
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        } 
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}


Still not working.

CreateDialog() requires that you pass a DLGPROC, not a WNDPROC. Also, you need to manually set focus to the first control. Otherwise, keyboard navigation won't work.

@IInspectable the code wouldn't compile in the first place if cVentana was not declared as DLGPROC when passing it to CreateDialog(). The only difference between the signatures of DLGPROC and WNDPROC is the return value type (INT_PTR vs LRESULT). But in any case, a DLGPROC does need to use SetWindowLong(DWL_MSGRESULT) when returning values to certain messages, whereas a WNDPROC doesn't.
